# mtproto/core js, события из Telegram спустя время перестают приходить

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, mtproto

Для работы с Telegram Api на node использую библиотеку mtproto/core. Мне необходимо получать обновления в реальном времени. Библиотека даёт такую возможность.

```
mtproto.updates.on('updates', (updateInfo) => {
  console.log('updates:', updateInfo);
});
```

Однако этот метод перестаёт работать спустя минут 10. То есть обновления приходят и спустя 10 минут перестают приходить. Окей, я сделал setInterval для получения текущего состояния обновлений.

```
setInterval(async function () {
    await api.call('updates.getState', {});
  }, 10000);
```

Это позволило получать обновления в течении 4-6 часов. Но обновления всё равно перестают приходить. Окей, я попробовал в setInterval засунуть и получение обновлений.

```
setInterval(async function () {
    mtproto.updates.on('updates', (updateInfo) => {
  console.log('updates:', updateInfo);
});
  }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4);
```

Это не помогло. Будто он останавливает соединение с telegram, когда события не приходят скажем час или более, сложно зафиксировать данный момент, да и в документации об этом нет ни одной строчки.
Можно попробовать, каждый час отправлять себе сообщение, тогда и события теоретически будут приходить каждый час. Но это кажется звучит как костыль.
Если кто-то работал с этим, буду премного благодарен за пару строк консультации. Спасибо.

Ну и на крайней случай, если кто-то работал с gramjs, расскажите, там с этим всё в порядке? Может имеет смысл поменять библиотеку?

Comment: Удалось решить проблему? Был бы очень признателен если выйдешь на связь!